# Cloud Code Password Protection Parse.com

Tags: .htaccess, express, parse-platform, password-protection

I have three apps on Parse.com one is my DEV environment, one is my QA environment and one is my live Production environment. Is there anyway to completely block my DEV and QA sites from the outside world? Typically I would do this using .htaccess, but that's obviously not an option.

I know that I can use basicAuth in my express.js setup, but that seems to only work for a designated endpoint. Is there anyway to set that up to cover the entire root domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out...

var basicAuth = express.basicAuth('xxxxx','xxxxxx');
app.use('/',basicAuth);

Comment: I'm trying to do this as well. Could you please explain where to implement this solution. I'd appreciate that very much.

Comment: It should be in the same spot where you configure the rest of the server options. I believe it's the app.js file.

Comment: Sorry, I cant get the markdown to work in this comment :/

What I am doing is: 
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var basicAuth = express.basicAuth('Don','Santo');
app.use('/', basicAuth);
app.listen();

Comment: Ok, I've got it. Basically doing '/' does not trigger authentication on the root level. Thanks.